# How to delete an Excel worksheet with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to delete some worksheet from an Excel file (2007), i challenged to write on cells or get values from cell but i dont challenge to delete worksheet

I tried this code

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(PATH_FICHIER_TRAITES."CONCAT/Concat_".$file);
$nombreFeuille = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
if($nombreFeuille>1){
      for($i=1; $i<=$nombreFeuille; $i++){
           $objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex($i);    
      }
} 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->save(PATH_FICHIER_TRAITES."CONCAT/Concat_".$file);
```

but my file remain the same after the execution

I would be thankful if u could offer me some help :)

Answer (score 0):

As the worksheet index starts from 0 (not from 1), there is no sheet index that will equal the value of `$nombreFeuille`, so this code should be throwing and exception.
As you're not catching that exception anywhere in your code, it will never instantiate the writer, or save the file